# Jquery Calculator Decimal Point

Tags: jquery, decimal, tofixed

I have been trying to work out for the last day how to add a decimal point onto the total of my calculator.

http://www.waveleisure.co.uk/calc/

Its probably best to check out that link, the monthly saving works but I cant seem to get the price to format in .00 .

The script is here, (http://www.waveleisure.co.uk/calc/js/myscript.js) its a modified version of one i found online? Any ideas, I have tried toFixed(4); to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
var total = (+aaa + +bbb + +ccc).toFixed(2);
$("#total").val(total);
```

after lines 116, 184 and 253 in myscript.js and replace all instances where you have

```
Math.round((+aaa + +bbb + +ccc) *4 - value).toFixed(2);
```

with

```
((aaa + +bbb + +ccc) *4 - value).toFixed(2)
```

of course replacing `value` with the original constant in the code

Comment: Thanks mate, been pulling my hair out for days, this fixed it straight away :D

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are rounding off the answer

```
// Total Saving Scriptt
var savingchoice = Math.round((+aaa + +bbb + +ccc) *4 - 41).toFixed(2);
```

Change this to

```
var savingchoice = ((aaa + +bbb + +ccc) *4 - 41).toFixed(2);
```

Math.round rounds to nearest *Integer value*, so you will lose digits after decimal value.

Comment: I tried your code and unfortunately it did not work, thanks the reply anyway.

Comment: @BrentFrench did you remove all the math.round instances fromyour code??

Comment: yeah tried it on my local box, chridam solution worked thanks for the input anyway